# Unable to log in to tty1

Tags: arch-linux, tty

#### Issue

Some strange thing is happening on my system as I try to log in to tty1. After I enter the `username` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the prompt drops to a newline instead of `password`. After hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the `password` is displayed. After hitting the first character of `password`, it again drops to a newline. After that while I am entering `password`, it shows `Login Incorrect` and repeats the whole thing. I can successfully Login via other `ttys`.

#### What I tried

```
systemctl stop getty@tty1
systemctl start getty@tty1
```

The issue still persists afterwards.

#### System

- Arch Linux
- `uname -a` produces `Linux Ceda 4.9.6-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Jan 26 09:22:26 CET 2017 x86_64 GNU/Linux`
- Output of `systemctl status getty@tty1` [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/jebWc9Sv)

#### Last changes

- Installing `snapd` and one `snap` package - `ohmygiraffe`
- Installing `arch-kde-git` from `AUR`

I personally don't think any of these can affect the system.

#### Edit 1

Output of `sudo lsof /dev/tty1`

```
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1000/gvfs
  Output information may be incomplete.
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
plymouthd  75 root    7u   CHR    4,1      0t0   20 /dev/tty1
plymouthd  75 root    9u   CHR    4,1      0t0   20 /dev/tty1
plymouthd  75 root   10u   CHR    4,1      0t0   20 /dev/tty1
plymouthd  75 root   11u   CHR    4,1      0t0   20 /dev/tty1
plymouthd  75 root   12u   CHR    4,1      0t0   20 /dev/tty1
plymouthd  75 root   14u   CHR    4,1      0t0   20 /dev/tty1
systemd-l 604 root   20u   CHR    4,1      0t0   20 /dev/tty1
agetty    978 root    0u   CHR    4,1      0t0   20 /dev/tty1
agetty    978 root    1u   CHR    4,1      0t0   20 /dev/tty1
agetty    978 root    2u   CHR    4,1      0t0   20 /dev/tty1
```

**Note**: *I had plymouth installed but I had installed it a week back but the issue wasn't present after that time. Also `sudo locate plymouth` gives no result. So I have no idea about where the plymouth in the above output comes from*

#### Edit 2

I am able to login after doing `sudo killall plymouthd`. However, `sudo systemctl status plymouthd` returns `Unit plymouthd.service could not be found.`

Comment: Can you do `lsof /dev/tty1` and see if there's anything other than a single getty process with it open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was with the `plymouth` hook being executed `mkinitcpio` at startup which itself did not exist and somehow caused issues with the `tty`. I removed `plymouth` from `HOOKS` section in `/etc/mkinitpcio.conf` and ran `mkinitpcio -p linux` as `root`. The issue was resolved upon `reboot`.